# django send_notification UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character

Tags: python, django, heroku, notifications

I can't quite figure this one out with the information available on similar questions, so here goes. Basically I have a simple command that sends an email to my users based on some criteria. It loops through a list or recipients and sends an email to anyone who fits the criteria. It works fine locally with a few emails, but when I push my side to heroku and loop through my list of users, I get the following error. I don't think it's a heroku issue, but I don't have a good way to troublshoot:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character
```

Here is my simple command:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, time
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from django.core.mail import send_mass_mail, EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from notifications.mail import send_notification
from users.models import User

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        now = timezone.now()
        day = str(settings.WEEKLY_EMAIL_STATUS_DAY)
        email_go = str(settings.WEEKLY_EMAIL_STATUS)
        last_login_time = timezone.now() - timedelta(days=7)

        if email_go == ("True"):
            if now.strftime("%A").encode('utf-8') == day:
                recipients = list(User.objects.filter(weekly_updates=True, last_login__lte=last_login_time ))
                send_notification(recipients, "notifications/weekly_account_update.txt")
```

Here is the mail.py which is used:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
import re
import mimetypes

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.mail import send_mass_mail, EmailMultiAlternatives
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import Context
from email.mime.text import MIMEText


def send_notification(recipient, template, **variables):

    """Also accepts list of `recipient`s which will send a mail to each."""
    if isinstance(recipient, list):
        recipients = recipient
    else:
        recipients = [recipient]

    variables['root_url'] = settings.PUBLIC_URL_ROOT
    messages = []
    for recipient in recipients:
        variables['recipient'] = recipient
        message = get_template(template).render(Context(variables))
        subject, html_content = re.split(r'\n+', message.strip(), maxsplit=1)

        for message in messages:
            message = EmailMultiAlternatives(html_content)
            message = MIMEText(html_content, 'html')
            message.content_subtype = "html"

        messages.append((
            subject,
            html_content,
            settings.NOTIFACTION_FROM_ADDRESS,
            [recipient.email]))



    send_mass_mail(messages, fail_silently=False)
    logger.info("Sent %r email to %s" % (template, ', '.join(r.email for r in recipients)))
```

weekly_account_update.txt:

```
{% load cents %}
{% autoescape on %}You've got {{recipient.account.balance|credits}} unspent credits.{%   endautoescape %}

Hey {% autoescape on %}{{recipient.first_name}}{{recipient.last_name}}{% endautoescape %},

You've got {{recipient.account.balance|credits}} unspent credits left to use. Here's some great stuff you could be reading and supporting: {{root_url}}{% url 'home' %}#trending


-Team
```

Comment: Could you post the stack trace to identify which line is causing the error?

Comment: please post the content of weekly_account_update.txt

Comment: Hey @arocks, I don't really get a good trace, and that's my struggle with the troublshooting effort. i.e. from my logs I get:2014-02-11T22:49:06.589988+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `python manage.py weekly_credit_update` by me then nothing outside of a naive datetimewarning, then i get a big red error:UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)